# Disable scanning of CD/DVD drive during windows boot

Tags: windows-7, boot, dvd, compact-disc

How can i find which program is scanning the dvd/cd drive during windows 7 boot up? I want to disable this. Maybe anti virus? (I use AVG)

I already changed boot priority on bios to make HD first. This scan happens after the windows logo appears.

This takes about 7 seconds, which is about 1/3 of boot time.

Comment: Amazing we can now be annoyed by a 7 second boot delay, we have become so spoiled with modern electronics!

Comment: @Moab the modern electronics that completely spoiled me is my new SSD :)

Comment: SSD + 7seconds = eternity :->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to create a report using the [Windows Performance Analysis Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/cc825801) - especially the `xperf.exe` and `xbootmgr.exe` tool. I assume that the delay and the responsible program/driver should be easily detectable in the system startup trace.

For details how to use this tools see the article [Measuring Performance on Windows Embedded Standard 7](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/6/2/862977E5-8D21-4A1C-8DC9-C2289244C14C/Measuring%20Performance%20on%20Windows%20Embedded%20Standard%207.pdf).

Comment: thanks! this is awesome. so i found out that it's the windows pnp driver scanning the cd drive. i guess i can't work around this one :/

Comment: ok.. found it's the marvell 61xx ide driver...